# Unregistered profiles are shown as registered

Tags: bug, profile-page, moderator-tools, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I was looking the profile of a new user, as moderator of *Drupal Answers*, and I noticed that it is reported both as unregistered, and registered.

> [image: screenshot]

What is correct? Is the account registered or not? Why is the page giving two different statuses?
I take this is a bug which involves the Communities list as shown to moderators.

The account for which I saw the screenshot is https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/55224/drupal-8-test, but I noticed the same for other accounts.

Comment: Schrödinger's user?

Comment: I didn't know Stack Exchange was going to join the EU. `;)`

Comment: Only moderators see the (registered) under the Communities list, so tagging this as part of moderator tools. Pretty sure the account is indeed unregistered, and there is a bug in the Communities list for moderators.

Comment: I'm seeing this on SO too. I assumed that there was caching involved as the accounts where I noticed it were new spammer accounts that I was actually in the process of destroying.

Comment: @ChrisF no caching or synchronization here as far as I can tell, because ordinary account can't suddenly become unregistered, only the other way around.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It could be caching, if the part being cached is _Drupal 8 test (unregistered)_. I would expect to be the Communities list to be cached, though; this seems improbable, in this case, since it would mean the user account passed from registered to unregistered (which is impossible).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it's a bug too. Maybe I will retag the question, later today.

Comment: Yup, good idea as bug has better chance to draw the team's attention. :)

Comment: Still doing that, a year later.

Comment: ...Is this still happening? From what I can tell, the profile page design has changed such that the "(registered)"/"(unregistered)" isn't displayed under the "Communities" list on the left.

Comment: @V2Blast On `users/account-info/<user-id>` I can still see "registered"ㅤ/"unregistered" in the Communities list and in the user profile page. I have not seen what I reported here after this case, but I cannot say it does not happen anymore.

Comment: (OK, the invisible-space trick does not work on comments and I cannot shown two close words in italics.)

Comment: At least, on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/account-info/55224 I see *unregistered* shown on both the places.